# Is it possible to tell what change has been made to a constraint in GCP and who made them?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to generate a report that identify 1) what are all new constraints added in GCP, who added them,2)also want to identify if any change is made to the existing constraints and what is that change,
3)  want to identify the constraints that are deleted

Is it possible to get this information about the constraints in GCP???

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the logs at the organisation level on that query `protoPayload.serviceName="orgpolicy.googleapis.com"`. Then create a [Cloud Logging Sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) to save all the matching entry somewhere (in BigQuery or in PubSub, as you wish). Use the [aggregated sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks) feature to include all the folders and project (in case of org policy change at lower level)

Finally, process the JSON payload to extract all the required data for your use cases.

Comment: Does the above query Identifies if a change is made to a constraint nd when it is deleted??

Comment: It filters all the logs that interact with org policy API. Now, what's a "change" for you? A change on a global value at Org level? Create an exception at folder or project level? In both case it's a "change" from my perspective.

Comment: Got it. Yes change in a value or policy at org level or at a folder or project level. Is it possible to create an alert whenever a constraint is created or deleted..

Comment: Yes, you can add the method name in the filter: `methodName: "google.cloud.orgpolicy.v2.OrgPolicy.DeletePolicy"` or `methodName: "google.cloud.orgpolicy.v2.OrgPolicy.CreatePolicy"` to get the relevant logs. You can also create an alert on a Log-based metric if you want an alert automatically managed by Cloud Monitoring.

Comment: Is the above filtering done at project level?? Can we create an alert if I filter the above methods at org level??

Comment: Yes org level + include-child option to include all the child resources